# Simple way to change azimutal axis with perspective library

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3d

I use the great `tikz` `perspective` library by Max Snippe and I need to change the axes definition so that the vertical (azimutal) one is not `z` anymore.

I'm pretty sure there is a simple and efficient way to do that without losing library capabilities.

So instead of the following

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{3d,perspective}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[3d view={-30}{30}]
\draw[->] (0,0,0)coordinate(O) node[below]{O} --  (1,0,0)node[below]{x};
\draw[->] (O) --  (0,1,0)node[left]{y};    
\draw[->] (O) --  (0,0,1)node[right]{z}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

I would achieve:
[image]

without having to cheat on the coordinates like I did here:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[3d view={-30}{30}]
\draw[->] (0,0,0)coordinate(O1) node[above]{O} --  (1,0,0)node[below]{x};
\draw[->] (O1) --  (0,1,0)node[left]{z};    
\draw[->] (O1) --  (0,0,-1)node[right]{y}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Is there a way to redefine the axes as options, such as `[x=x, y=-z, z=y]` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redefine the axes, but also in this case you can rotate them around the x-axis.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{3d,perspective}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[3d view={-30}{30},rotate around x=270]
\draw[->] (0,0,0)coordinate(O) node[above]{O} --  (1,0,0)node[below]{x};
\draw[->] (O) --  (0,1,0)node[right]{y};    
\draw[->] (O) --  (0,0,1)node[left]{z}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The above code yields:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I knew the option, but never had the idea to use it that way!